# Create a foreign key constraint in a stored procedure with input primary key table name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm writing a stored procedure that creates a table whose name is provided as an input.  I've accomplished this by creating the table with a temporary name `_TMP`:

```
--Create the table with a temp name since the variable name
--cannot be used in the "CREATE TABLE" statement.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_TMP]
(
    [EntryID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK__TMP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [EntryID] ASC
    )
    WITH 
    (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
    )
)
```

and then renaming it like this:

```
EXEC SP_RENAME N'_TMP', @TargetTableName
```

Now I want to add another input which is the name of an *existing* primary key table so I can setup a foreign key relationship in my new table.  Assume I've also created the FK column in my new table called `ParentEntryID`.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[_TMP]  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__TMP__TMP_PARENT] FOREIGN KEY([ParentEntryID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[_TMP_PARENT] ([EntryID]) -- <-- this won't work b/c there's no such table _TMP_PARENT

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[_TMP] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__TMP__TMP_PARENT]
```

The problem, as indicated above in the comment, is that the procedure will fail because I can't provide the actual primary key table name with the `REFERENCES` clause.  **Is there a system sp that can handle variable table names for setting up foreign key relationships?**  I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question (sorry), but can you create the table and then create the FK with an EXEC(string) command instead?  Also - you'll either want to use the new table's name for the constraints or rename them as well ... or you will only be able to execute this thing the one time ;-)

Comment: @bri -- thanks, yes I left out the renaming of the constraints for brevity.  I was hoping to do this without dynamic sql.

Comment: What you want is a bit of a fringe case, and Dynamic SQL is pretty much the only way to do this. Using `sp_executeSQL` is generally safer than `EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first place, you have design problem if you need to be creating tables with new names and the same structure.  This is not a good technique and is a a database antipattern.

However, if you are stuck with it, you need to create the table and the index using dynamic sql. Please lookup how to do that in Books online and read this article first:

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm interested to know more about why this is not a good technique and an antipattern.  Perhaps it would help if I explained what I'm doing:  These tables are log tables created for storing changes in certain data that happen elsewhere.  They are created with the same structure as a starting point because all such tables are expected to have a known set of meta fields.  Specific log data columns are added later by another process.  Some log tables share a parent/child relationship -- hence my question.  If you can direct me to an alternative approach, I'd be happy.

Comment: ...or more reading about this antipattern (what's it called specifically so I can look it up?)